# Example of usage Subquery in django orm

Tags: django

What is the difference between two queries? Because I see identical queries  through queryset.query.

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(is_active=True).values_list("pk", flat=True)
Post.objects.filter(category_id__in=Subquery(categories))
```

vs

```
Post.objects.filter(category_id__in=Category.objects.filter(is_active=True).values_list("pk", flat=True))
```

**And how to use Subquery properly? In what cases?** Can anyone explain with examples Subquery, Outref etc?

Comment: The two queries are equivalent as you yourself say. The first one is simply being explicit about the subquery.

Comment: What's interesing is that you can probably (depending on your mdels) write , to the same effect, something like `Post.objects.filter(category__is_active=True)`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.